# After onclick no error detect but cannot post into my database

Tags: javascript

this is my form name

```
<form name="form" id="form" method="post">
```

this my onclick

```
<input type="submit"
   name="submit"
  value="Register"
onclick="return validate()" />
```

this is my validate()

```
function validate() 
{
 var f = document.forms['form'];
 var ary=[checkfname,checklname,checkEmail,checkAge,checkAdd,validtp,validhp,checkName,validpass];
 var rtn=true;
 var z0=0;
 for (var z0=0;z0<ary.length;z0++)
 {
 if (!ary[z0](f))
  {
    rtn=false;
  }
 }
 return rtn;
}
```

i think is my validate return there cannot return to post

hope someone can help me to solve the problem,thx...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are storing an array of functions that make different validations:

```
var ary=[checkfname,checklname,checkEmail,checkAge,checkAdd,validtp,validhp,checkName,validpass];
```

Then you iterate that array and each function is executed receiving the form as parameter.

```
!ary[z0](f)
```

If you return false, the default action will be prevented, in this case the form won't be submitted.

So I'm pretty sure one of your validations is returning false. You should check each one of those functions and see wich one is returning false - you could debug using tools such as chrome dev tools or firebug.